# Showing a set is open with respect to box vs product topology

Tags: general-topology, product-space, box-topology

I am currently studying topology with Munkres and I am asking for some general proof techniques and clarification rather than just posting my question and wait for a solution. I am given that the real line is endowed with the euclidean topology and also given a subset of the real line. My task is to show that this subset is open with respect to the box topology, but not open with respect to the product topology.

My question is what is different between the box and product topologies such that a set would be open in the box topology and not open in the product topology? I am familiar with the different bases used to generate each topology, but I am lost as to how the same set could be open with respect to the box topology but not open with respect to the product topology

Answer (score 3):

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $X_n=\Bbb R$, and let $X=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=(0,1)$, the open unit interval, and let $U=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$. By definition $U$ is open in the box topology on $X$: it’s even a basic open set.

It is not open in the product topology, however; in fact, it doesn’t even contain any non-empty open set in the product topology. Remember, the usual base for the product topology is the family of all sets of the form $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}V_n$ such that each $V_n$ is open in $X_n$, and $\{n\in\Bbb N:V_n\ne X_n\}$ is finite. In other words, all but finitely many of the sets $V_n$ are all of $X_n$. If $U$ were open, it would contain one of these sets, but in fact it does not.

To see this, observe that if $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}V_n\subseteq\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$, then $V_n\subseteq U_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. If $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}V_n$ is a basic open set in the product topology, then $V_n=X_n=\Bbb R$ for all but finitely many $n\in\Bbb N$. Pick any $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $V_n=X_n$; then $$V_n=\Bbb R\nsubseteq(0,1)=U_n\,,$$ so $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}V_n\nsubseteq\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$.

To put it informally, basic open sets in the box topology can restrict **every** coordinate, while basic open sets in the product topology can restrict only **finitely many** coordinates. Thus, you can get basic open sets in the box topology that don’t contain any basic open set in the product topology and therefore are not open in the product topology (and indeed have empty interior).

Comment: So in terms of proof technique to follow, when given a set (call this set S) and left to prove that it is not open in the product topology, it is sufficient to show that S does not contain any basis elements for the product topology, ie S does not contain any basic open sets in the product topology?

Comment: @Caden: Yes, that’s sufficient (provided that $S\ne\varnothing$), though not necessary: a set can fail to be open for other reasons.

Comment: In that case: In general, if we are given the task "Prove some set S is open/not open with respect to some topology" what would be the best approach to that proof? In other words, what is/are the determining factor(s) for a set being open with respect to a topology? EDIT: If it would help, I could share the exact problem I am working with, but as stated in the original post I am mainly looking to be pointed in the right direction for the proof and not simply read/copy an answer.

Comment: @Caden: In general the best approach is going to depend heavily on the specific space and set and what is known about them; I’m afraid that your question is a bit too general to admit a really useful answer.

Comment: Understandable. I will continue doing some research and reading. Thank you so much! Definitely cleared up a lot

Comment: @Caden: You’re welcome!